# TeamViewer VPN Linux-to-Windows equivalent

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, ubuntu-10.04, teamviewer

I have a Linux Computer that I want to connect via VPN to a Windows Computer, but I need it to be easy to connect like TeamViewer is. I need it to be real simple because I'm setting this up for someone that has to access a work network from their Linux machine but they aren't that tech savvy so anything complicated will just get them confused. I like how in TeamViewer you just have to type the ID and password and it'll connect. No other complicated processes it's just open, enter ID & password, and connect. Dead simple. Is their anything of equivalence for a Linux Computer to connect to Windows?

NOTE: An idea I had while writing this was to simply install TeamViewer in a normal Wine install with the latest Windows version since the Linux Version is just a Windows install run through a trimmed down Wine. Could this work for the VPN or is their no way to connect a Windows VPN through Wine?

Answer (score 6):

You might be interesting in VPN over the Internet without dedicated public IP, when all the nodes are behind the NAT. Those connections called F2F (Friend to Friend) or P2PVPN (Point to Point VPN). They might be fully decentralized or may require initial connection broker like XMPP Jabber or Google Hangout (required only at time of establishing connections between end hosts). In both types of connections traffic goes directly from host to host.

<kbd>**`VPN Name`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`VPN Type`**</kbd>         <kbd>**`Auth. Method`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`Peer Disc.`**</kbd><kbd>**`NAT Traversal`**</kbd>

<kbd>`GBridge`</kbd>   <kbd>`Centralized P2P`</kbd>  <kbd>`Pwd @centr srv`</kbd><kbd>`Centr srv`</kbd> <kbd>`Yes, centr. relay`</kbd>    
<kbd>`Wippien`</kbd>   <kbd>`Centralized P2P`</kbd>  <kbd>`Pwd @centr srv`</kbd><kbd>`Centr srv`</kbd> <kbd>`Yes, no relay`</kbd>        
<kbd>`P2PVPN`</kbd>    <kbd>`Unstructured P2P`</kbd> <kbd>`Shared secret`</kbd> <kbd>`Broadcast`</kbd> <kbd>`No, decentraliz relay`</kbd>
<kbd>`IPOP`</kbd>      <kbd>`Structured P2P`</kbd>   <kbd>`PKI/pr.ex. key`</kbd><kbd>`DHT lookup`</kbd><kbd>`Yes,relay:close peers`</kbd>
<kbd>`GNUNet`</kbd>    <kbd>`Unstructured P2P`</kbd>               <kbd>`DHT lookup`</kbd><kbd>`Yes`</kbd>                  
<kbd>`pwnat`</kbd>     <kbd>`P2P`</kbd>              <kbd>`?`</kbd>             <kbd>`ICMP hack`</kbd> <kbd>`Yes`</kbd>                  
<kbd>`ZeroTier`</kbd>  <kbd>`P2P`</kbd>              <kbd>`Crypto Keys`</kbd>   <kbd>`SUTN-like`</kbd> <kbd>`Yes`</kbd>

[Comparison](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.2575.pdf) can be found here.

Comment: Another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118006/vpn-with-webrtc-stun-ice

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the Linux version but the Windows version works fine through Wine.

Comment: Does TeamViewer's VPN feature work through Wine though?

Answer (score 1):

[Openvpn](http://openvpn.net/) has lots of [frontends](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RelatedProjects)

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, I used Hamachi for this. 
https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/
Not tried it since, but at one time, it was that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for a pptp client solution instead of a complex software such as OpenVPN which can be difficult to setup? It is well supported in Linux with many frontends and it is native to windows. With PPTP you have your username and password and that's it. Setup the server on windows, the client on Linux, click on the connect button and you're done.

[PPTP Linux](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/)

What Linux distro are you using? [This](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-pptp-gui-to-connect-windows-vpn-in-ubuntu.html) is for Ubuntu.