# VPN software similar to Hamachi, Remobo or GBridge?

Tags: vpn, firewall, nat, hamachi

I am looking for a VPN software that will run on Windows (Mac/Linux would be a bonus), that are similar to other packages such as Hamachi that will automatically work behind a NAT or Firewall.    Also, it needs to run as a service, so the user does not have to be logged in.  I can run my own server if need be.

Hamachi, Remobo and GBridge are great, but they are limited to the number of machines you are allowed for free, or do not allow running as a background service.

I see there are some open source possibilities - OpenVPN,  n2n, but I am not sure if they will do the  windows/service/nat-firewall.

LeafNetworks looks like it might do the trick, I am going to try it out, but I am just concerned that it appears free for now, but then at some point it may become pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenVPN clients can run as a Windows Deamon behind NAT. The server however will need some additional configuration to work with NAT. But that shouldn't be a problem.

See more info here: [Running OpenVPN as a Windows Service](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1)

As you need to run your own server for OpenVPN, paying for it is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something similar to Hamachi take a look at [SocialVPN](http://socialvpn.wordpress.com/) project...

Comment: Here is the [list of alternative apps](http://serverfault.com/a/746572/100769) for F2F / P2PVPN.

Answer (score 2):

tinc seems great : http://www.tinc-vpn.org

I'm planning to use it.

m2c