# Comunication from Server to Client + Client LAN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, local-area-network

I'm having some trouble with some network setup. I've tried OpenVPN, SocialVPN, Hamachi, still it is not working.
This is my setup:
Server A: NIC 1 with internet public address, NIC 2 to LAN
Client B PC: NIC 1 (192.168.10.2) connects to router 192.168.10.1
Client B Device: 192.168.10.3 (Configured via software, can't do much here)

Problem:
Server A must connect to cliente device B. (I can install software needed at Client B PC).
However... I can't change the router to some model with VPN like Draytek or Cisco :(
Also, I Client B doesn't need to talk to Server A LAN.

OpenVPN fails at bridging, PC B can ping Server A, but Server A can't ping Device B, only PC B.
What else can I do?!?!?

Comment: Here is the [list of alternative apps](http://serverfault.com/a/746572/100769) for F2F / P2PVPN.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Client B shares NIC 1 with OpenVPN and it's ok.
Also, IPforwarding must be enabled at registry (Win7).
No need to mess around OpenVPN bridged mode.